# Creating a login that works with ASP.Net and DynamoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently trying to make a login system that works with ASP.Net and DynamoDB . It isn't meant to be super practical as I'm making it to show off functionally. I was wondering if anyone with experience would be able to tell me 
1. If it is actually possible
2. If it's at all practical 
3. If it's secure

The idea i have in my head at the moment is to pull the login information off a userslogin table and verify it with a simple if else statement. I was then going to restrict access to the rest of the webapp depending on whether a login variable was set to true. This would be held in a session variable.

I was just curious as I am only using Dynamo a few days, to see if this makes any sense or I'm wasting my own time.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes its possible for a completely insecure login.

1. Have the  user enter userid and password.
2. Connect to the dynamodb using the awssdk and the IAM credentials that have the correct rights,
3. Query or scan the dynamodb table to see if you find a user with the same userid and password that the user entered.
4. If there is a match, return true, if not, return false.
5. Set your session variable with the true/false returned above.

So yes its possible, trivially easy, but a very insecure and easily hacked solution - use with caution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , It's just to show off assignment work it isn't going to be used as a practical solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Voting you down because of the "security theater" and the fact that you're not explaining yourself while making wild accusations about a system used by banks.

Please clarify your statements about the security of a login using dynamodb; What about using Dynamo DB to build a login inherently makes it insecure?  The fact is, your wrong and your making false statements, respectfully.